# Export XMLType columns from table to multiple files using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, export, xmltype

I have a table with a schema that looks something like this:

```
Name         Null     Type                        
------------ -------- --------------------------- 
ID           NOT NULL NUMBER                      
XML_DOCUMENT          XMLTYPE()                   
CREATED_TS            TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
TRAN_ID               NUMBER
```

What I want to do is something like export every XML_DOCUMENT column to a file where TRAN_ID = (something).

So for example if I want TRAN_ID=10, if there are 20 rows with TRAN_ID=10 then I want to get 20 xml files that correspond with the XML_DOCUMENT column.

I tried:

```
create or replace directory exp_dir as '/path/to/something';

begin
  for c in (select xml_document,id from my_table where tran_id=10) loop
    dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(c.xml_document.getClobVal(), 'EXP_DIR', 'document' || c.id);
 end loop;
end;
```

This runs for awhile leading me to believe it's doing something, then says it finished successfully. However, when I check the directory '/path/to/something' it's empty.

I'm just looking for some to help to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, since that looks OK; are you looking in that directory on the database server, or on a separate client machine?

Comment: It was on my local machine. I didn't think to see if they were on the database server ( directory I was trying to write to probably doesn't exist there, wouldn't that throw an error?) I'll have to check tomorrow morning further.

Comment: Yes, it would error if the directory didn't exist,so presumably it does. You can only write to directories on the server.